# How do I make dependent queries in react-query?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-query

I have a component called `Sidebar.tsx` that is fetching some data here but I want to only fetch levels only if `studentId` is available. I looked through dependent queries on `react-query` [documentation](https://react-query.tanstack.com/guides/dependent-queries) . I applied that in my code but it looks like it doesn't work. Here's is what I did.

First of all I fetched the `studentId` from an API too, here is how it looks like:

```
  const studentId = intakeProgramStore.getStudentShipByUserId(authUser?.id)
.data?.data.data[0];
```

Now another function to get programs

```
class IntakeProgramStore{

  getIntakeProgramsByStudent(studentId: string) {
    return useQuery(
      ['intakeProgram/studentId', studentId],
      () => intakeProgramService.getIntakeProgramsByStudent(studentId),
      { enabled: !!studentId },
    );
  }
}

export const intakeStore = new IntakeProgramStore();
```

This function is located in `stores/intake.store.ts` and what it does is that when it gets called it calls a service method called `intakeProgramService.getIntakeProgramsByStudent` which is also imported at the top and it works fine as expected. The problem I have here is that it is calling that service even if `studentId` is undefined while it was supposed to call it when it has a value.

Here's how I'm calling it inside `Sidebar.tsx` which is my UI component

```
 const programs = intakeProgramStore.getIntakeProgramsByStudent(student.id)
.data?.data.data[0];
```

I moved the code that was in the `stores/intake.store.ts` file into `Sidebar.tsx` and now it worked fine but I don't know why. Here's how it looks

```
const programs = useQuery(
['intakeProgram/studentId', student?.id],
() => intakeProgramService.getIntakeProgramsByStudent(student?.id),
{ enabled: !!student
```

I'm not sure why it's not working when I'm fetching inside the store but works when I do it in the UI component.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally, your code looks correct. The only thing that I *can* see is that in the first example, you're calling `useQuery` inside a function called `getIntakeProgramsByStudent`, which is an invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called:

- by functional react components
- inside *custom hooks*, which are functions that start with `use...`.

see also the [rules of hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html#only-call-hooks-from-react-functions) react documentation.

A custom hook for your useQuery call would be:

```
export const useIntakeProgramsByStudent(studentId: string) {
  return useQuery(
    ['intakeProgram/studentId', studentId],
    () => intakeProgramService.getIntakeProgramsByStudent(studentId),
    { enabled: !!studentId },
  );
}
```

Comment: The function is found in a class. I've updated the example for more clarity.

Comment: Doesn’t matter - it still violates the rules of hooks, which has nothing to do with react-query - it’s just how react works.

Comment: I guess they always show errors when you do an invalid hook call. Like when you call a `useQuery` hook inside another react hook they show a warning but they're not doing so in my case. Do you suggest maybe another way to define that function instead of putting it under a class ?

Comment: if you call useQuery inside another hook there is no warning, because it is allowed to call hooks from other other hooks (also called custom hooks). I have amended my answer to show your useQuery call inside a custom hook. You can use this hook in all functional components or other custom hooks, but not from inside classes, "regular functions" or class components.

Comment: It does show an error when I call it inside `useEffect`.

Comment: of course it does, you can't call hooks in callbacks. Please read the react docs about hooks and rules of hooks linked above, because that's just not how hooks work.

Comment: oh yeah, I think now it makes sense. I'll try that example and see if it works for me.